# PHP & MySQL array question

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add the articles id to the title, summary and content but I don't know how to do it can some one help me solve this problem.

Here is the code that is giving me the problem.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    $id[] = $row['id'];
    $title[] = $row['id']['title'];
    $summary[] = $row['id']['summary'];
    $content[] = $row['id']['article_content'];
}
```

And here is my PHP and MySQL code in full below.

```
$x = 0;
$con = null;
$search = $_REQUEST['search'];
$id = array();
$title = array();
$summary = array();
$content = array(); 

$search_explode = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $search);
$search_explode = explode(' ', $search_explode);

foreach($search_explode as $search_each) {
    $x++;
    if($x == 1){
        $con .= " article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    } else {
        $con .= " OR article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    }
}

$con = "SELECT users.*, users_articles.* FROM users_articles
              INNER JOIN users ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
              WHERE ($con) 
              AND users.active IS NULL
              AND users.deletion = 0";

$run =  mysqli_query($dbc, $con);
$search_term = mysqli_num_rows($run);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    $id[] = $row['id'];
    $title[] = $row['id']['title'];
    $summary[] = $row['id']['summary'];
    $content[] = $row['id']['article_content'];
}
```

Comment: why the negative rating?

Comment: I think the negative votes comes, because some of members assume that you have basic knowledge to access data from database to PHP. Why not to go back and learn basics of PHP programming.

Comment: there is still no need for the negatives this is a legit question according to the rules.

Comment: @Salman A I asked what I stated in the question how to combine both the id and the title together for example

Comment: @negativeratingfools Show yourselves you negative rating cowards!!!!!!

Comment: @Wooh: welcome to stackoverflow. A properly phrased question gives you upvotes. If you do not get the  answers you expect, try to re-phrase your question and/or post current+expected output. Thank you :)

Comment: @Salman A good to know but still no reason for the negative ratings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    // $id[] = $row['id']; you probably do not need this anymore
    $title[$row['id']]   = $row['title'];
    $summary[$row['id']] = $row['summary'];
    $content[$row['id']] = $row['article_content'];
}

// at this point, each array will contain rows
// with keys matching the corresponding id
var_dump($title);
var_dump($summary);
var_dump($content);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help this is what I was looking for, what is the called exactly in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
$title[] = $row['id']['title'];
$summary[] = $row['id']['summary'];
$content[] = $row['id']['article_content'];
```

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` will fetch an associated array. Accessing the data directly like so `$row['summary']` should fix your problem.

**EDIT**

Are you talking about string concatenation?

```
$title[] = $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['title'];
$summary[] = $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['summary'];
$content[] = $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['article_content'];
```

The above code will basically append the title/summary/content to your article ID and add it into respective arrays.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that when you're joining tables, if you have common columns like `id`, the second table will overwrite the other. It's best to alias these table columns

Comment: This is not working its only displaying the ids and not the title I need both the id and title together for example.

Comment: something like that but can I put it into an array like a multidimensional array?

Comment: thanks for the help but Salman A solved for me sorry I could not be more informative.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve but I would suggest the the following solution. Please take a look.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  deletion int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  active int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `users`

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `name`, `deletion`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 'John', 0, 1),
(2, 'George', 0, 1);

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `users_articles`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_content` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `summary` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `users_articles`

INSERT INTO `users_articles` (`id`, `user_id`, `article_content`, `title`, `summary`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'test', 'test', 'test test test  test'),
(2, 2, 'test 2', 'test 2', 'test test'),
(3, 1, 'test 3', 'test 3 ', 'test test test  test 3'),
(4, 2, 'test 3', 'test 3', 'test test 3');

`<?php
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "articles");

            /* check connection */
            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
                exit();
            }

            /* Select queries return a resultset */
            $con = 1;
            $sql = "SELECT users.*, users_articles.* FROM users_articles
                          INNER JOIN users ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
                          WHERE ($con) 
                          AND users.active = 1
                          AND users.deletion = 0";
            $results = array();              
            if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
                printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
                print   '<pre>';
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $results[] = $row;
                }
                print_r($results);
            print   '</pre>';
                /* free result set */
                $result->close();
            }


            $mysqli->close();
            ?>`

and when you will iterate $results you can concatenate id and other fields in that case you can utilize the result array in other areas too.